# Textboxes don't clear themselves when page loaded

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

I have list of employers that binding to data and fill from special form. When I go to form I have every text boxes clear. I fill all of them and save new employer to list. But if I try to add new employer I have textboxes with previous text in form. And variables that bind to text boxes in form are all null.
Is there way to solve problem without using solution like that: Textbox.text=null;?
I'm using MVVM pattern in my app. I'm also using catel snippets to define viewmodel and properties. There is code of ViewModel of page with employer properties:

```
public EmployerModifyViewModel(TransferParameter parameter, IEmployersListManage employersListManager)
{
    //in "parameter" I pass values fo Current employer (it can be empty 
    //if we need to add new object to list or it can be some employer from list) 
    _employersListManager = employersListManager;
    SaveEmployerCommand = new Command(OnSaveEmployerCommandExecute);
    CanselSavingCommand = new Command(OnCanselSavingCommandExecute);
    if (parameter.Value is EmployerClass)
    {
        CurrentEmployer = parameter.Value as EmployerClass;
    }
}

public EmployerClass CurrentEmployer
{
    get { return GetValue<EmployerClass>(CurrentEmployerProperty); }
    private set { SetValue(CurrentEmployerProperty, value); }
}

/// <summary>
/// Register the CurrentEmployerBase property so it is known in the class.
/// </summary>
public static readonly PropertyData CurrentEmployerProperty = RegisterProperty("CurrentEmployer", typeof(EmployerClass), new EmployerClass());
```

There is example of binding to properties in xaml:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentEmployer, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ContentCntrol.Recources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type employer:EmployerClass}">
...
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                     x:Name="EmpName"
                     Width="300"
                     Height="30"
                     FontSize="14"
                     Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" //Property "Name" of CurrentEmployer
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     Margin="20,20,0,0"/>
```

Comment: Show the bindings and how you are defining your properties in the model. Are you using INotifyPropertyChanged properly if you have TwoWay binding?

Comment: are these in a template ? could be the template being reused!

Comment: Ok, I fixed my question and add more details. Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all, problem solved. I removed ContentControl and DataTemplate from xaml and I made bindings like this `"{Binding CurrentEmployer.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think u should use the below code where u add the new employee. Everytime the button is clicked the textboxes go empty.

```
            txtbox_1.Text = String.Empty;
            txtbox_2.Text = String.Empty;
            .............
```